# Limpiar caché en chrome con linux?

Tags: php, linux, vscode, cache

lo que sucede es que trabajo en linux con php y cuando modifico algo y lo recargo no funciona en la primera carga. le dí en la consola de chrome en disabled cache pero aun asi no funciona a la primera. Tambien le doy recargar con ctrl+r pero tampoco funciona. Tengo que hacerlo varias veces para que funcione lo cual es pérdida de tiempo. Alguien se sabe otra técnica que funcione mejor?

Answer (score 0):

Tienes 2 opciones:

- o **Ctrl + F5** que debería borrar cache y mostrar los cambios que hayas hecho.
- o creas un marcador borre todo al 100%.

  **·** Para hacerlo vas a Menú(puntitos arriba derecha) -> historial -> borrar datos de navegación *y en la modal emergente* -> configuración avanzada y marcas todo desde el principio de los tiempos pudiendo dejar el historial de navegación, auto completado de formularios y alguna cosa mas que no afecte. 

  **Antes de darle a Borrar datos** añades esa pagina a marcadores(estrella al lado de la url).
   De esa forma cada vez que quieras borrar cache de forma infalible solo tienes que darle a ese marcador y después a borrar datos.